# Why does the axiom of foundation hold for every class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why does the axiom of foundation hold for every class?

I came across this the other day but I'm not sure why it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a class and $x\in A$. Relativized axiom of foundation states
$$\forall x\in A:(x\neq\varnothing)^A.$$
You can see that $(x\neq\varnothing)^A$ iff $x\cap A$ is nonempty, and then you apply axiom of foundation for $x\cap A$.

Comment: Just curiosity (I am still learning): the notation $(x\neq\emptyset)^A$ stands for?... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @drhab It is the relativization of $x\neq\varnothing$ to $A$. Relativization is defined recursively (for formula) and $\phi^A$ means "$\phi$ holds in $A$".